# Embedded board level functional test at factory

Tags: embedded, gps, gsm, production-testing, test-equipment

My embedded project has a GSM and a GPS module. What is the best way to test the radios of these modules after the production of CCA like in a factory conditions.I was thinking of signal generators transmitting at the required frequencies. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Many factories can assist in testing hardware after assembly, see what they have to say.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your specific modules, but many devices that work through a bus have an acknowledge signal that the host can request.  Of course, that doesn't test the whole device, but if you get the high sign back it means the device is on the bus correctly and powered.